# How to modify components from api in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

I'm building a book library web app using NextJS and Strapi, in which people loan and borrow books.
I have some problems that I don't know how to solve;

1. How can I fetch data based on the user? What is the best way for authenticating user and fetching data based on their username or sth specific? (each user has specific items in their account)
2. How can I access and modify content-type component from api?
   [here I have some sent or received books components, how can I add items to them using API?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPi0R.png)

I've added some components to user_details content-type and each user that is authenticated here will have received and sent books, is it the right way to implement this?